Prevent control of the hosting environment by anyone launching containers from Jenkins or other non-root containers
I noticed that even if I launch a jenkins container as non-root, when I mount the socket as a volume /var/run/docker.sock Jenkins can launch container in the host environment as root and they can everything even manipulate /etc directory.
After creating a container where I added jenkins user to docker group, I launched it:
version: '3.9'

services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins:docker
    build: ./.docker/
    user: "${ID_USER}:${ID_GROUP}"
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - jenkins-net

networks:
  jenkins-net:

Where my Dockerfile in .docker is:
FROM jenkins/jenkins:latest

USER root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y lsb-release

RUN curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.asc \
  https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg
  
RUN echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) \
  signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.asc] \
  https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
  
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker-ce-cli

COPY ./.env .env

RUN groupadd docker && export $(cat ./.env) && \
    groupmod -g $ID_GROUP docker && usermod -aG docker jenkins

USER jenkins

Where my .env file is:
ID_USER=1000
ID_GROUP=999

Here ID_GROUP is ID_GROUP of docker group in this machine.
I tried to see if jenkins user could manage docker from the container and everything was ok:
docker compose exec jenkins docker ps

After that I went into the container with bash and tried typing:
docker run --rm -it -w /app -v /etc:/app ubuntu:latest touch test

and wrote a test file in /etc without any problems.
Is there a way to prevent someone who might take control of a jenkins container (or start one) from being able to launch containers in the host environment as root and be able to manipulate its file system?

You might look at running the Docker daemon in rootless mode. If that's not an option, then it's probably impossible to contain a malicious user that can run containers. It's very easy to gain root on the host if you can run containers.

I tend to think of "access to the Docker socket implies unrestricted root access to the host" as the first rule of Docker security.

@DavidMaze So can none use docker from a container jenkins?
